# Signal when QCalendarWidget popup opens?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qcalendarwidget

Here is function which is painting cells of some dates that were previously calculated and saved in the "dates" list, function is working fine but I want to call that function when QDateEdit is clicked(when popup calendar is shown)

```
def init_gui(self):
    # Set signals of widgets
    self.dockwidget.date_to.calendarWidget().clicked.connect(self.paint_cell) # !! the signal I'm looking for
def paint_cell(self):    
    #QDateEdit / QCalendarWidget Highlight Dates
    keyword_format = QTextCharFormat()
    keyword_format.setBackground(Qt.gray)
    for date in dates:
        self.dockwidget.date_from.calendarWidget().setDateTextFormat(QDate.fromString(date,"yyyy-MM-dd") ,keyword_format)
```

> self.dockwidget.date_from() # QDateEdit
>
> self.dockwidget.date_from.calendarWidget() # QCalendarWidget

I know that there are signals, but they are all working when QDate is clicked:
self.dockwidget.date_to.calendarWidget().activated.connect(self.paint_cell)
self.dockwidget.date_to.calendarWidget().clicked.connect(self.paint_cell)            self.dockwidget.date_to.calendarWidget().selectionChanged.connect(self.paint_cell)

but I have to paint the cells before these signals ,when the popup is displayed.

Does anyone know what that signal is?

[image]

NOTE: Code will be part of QGis plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with hints from @eyllanesc post, my working code now is:

```
class Project(QDockWidget):
    """ QGIS Plugin Implementation. """
    popupSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """ Constructor.

        :param iface: An interface instance that will be passed to this class
        which provides the hook by which you can manipulate the QGIS
        application at run time.
        :type iface: QgisInterface
        """
        QDockWidget.__init__(self)

        # Save reference to the QGIS interface
        self.iface = iface

        # initialize plugin directory
        self.plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

        ...

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.dockwidget.date_to.calendarWidget() is obj and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Show:
            self.popupSignal.emit()
        return super(Project, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

    ....

    def run(self):
       """ Run method that loads and starts the plugin """

           self.dockwidget.date_to.calendarWidget().installEventFilter(self)
           self.popupSignal.connect(self.paint_cell)


    def paint_cell(self):
        #QDateEdit / QCalendarWidget Highlight Dates
        keyword_format = QTextCharFormat()
        keyword_format.setBackground(Qt.gray)
        for date in dates:
             self.dockwidget.date_from.calendarWidget().setDateTextFormat(QDate.fromString(date, "yyyy-MM-dd"), keyword_format)
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use any signal if you want to set before displaying the calendarWidget, just call paint_cell in the constructor.

```py
# constructor
self.paint_cell()
self.dockwidget.date_to.calendarWidget().activated.connect(self.paint_cell)
# ...
```

**Update:**

There is no default signal for that circumstance, so believe it and you can use an event filter to monitor the Event.Show event and then emitted the signal.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class DateEdit(QtWidgets.QDateEdit):
    popupSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DateEdit, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setCalendarPopup(True)
        self.calendarWidget().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.calendarWidget() is obj and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Show:
            self.popupSignal.emit()
        return super(DateEdit, self).eventFilter(obj, event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = DateEdit()
    w.popupSignal.connect(lambda: print("popup"))
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I need to set signal, because every time when calendar will popup, there will be marked different dates (calculated on current state of canvas, layers, bbox ...) note: code will be part of QGis plugin

Comment: I was trying to avoid event filter, but in the end with a little bit of your code and with some modifications it's working now :) Thank you @eyllanesc